# In text classification, how to find the part of sentence that is important for the classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I have trained a text classification model that works well. I wanted to get deeper and understand what words/phrases from a sentence were most impactful in the classification outcome. I want to understand what words are most important for each classification outcome

I am using Keras for the classification and below is the code I am using to train the model. It's a simple embedding plus max-pooling text classification model that I am using.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping 

# early stopping
callbacks = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', min_delta=0, 
patience=5, verbose=2,  mode='auto', restore_best_weights=True)

# select optimizer
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999,
epsilon=1e-07, amsgrad=False, name="Adam")
embedding_dim = 50

# declare model
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, 
                           output_dim=embedding_dim, 
                           input_length=maxlen))
model.add(layers.GlobalMaxPool1D())
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer=opt,
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

# fit model
history = model.fit(X_tr, y_tr,
                    epochs=20,
                    verbose=True,
                    validation_data=(X_te, y_te),
                    batch_size=10, callbacks=[callbacks])
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_tr, y_tr, verbose=False)
```

How do I extract the phrases/words that have the maximum impact on the classification outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the keyword you need are "*neural network interpretability*" and "*feature attribution*". One of the best known methods in this area is called *Integrated Gradients*; it shows how model prediction depend on each input feature (each word embedding, in your case).

[This tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/interpretability/integrated_gradients) shows how to implement IG in pure tensorflow for images, and [this one](https://docs.seldon.io/projects/alibi/en/stable/examples/integrated_gradients_imdb.html) uses the `alibi` library to highlight the words in the input text with the highest impact on a classification model.